# Redirect to home path after successful login | React, Redux

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux

Hello people at Stack overflow! I want a user to be redirected when he/ she has been successfully logged into my app. However I can't get it to work. I thought I just could add a promise in my action after someone has been logged in, but apparently not.

Here's my **authentication** action:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import settings from '../settings'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

axios.defaults.baseURL = settings.hostname

export const login = ({ email, password }) => {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios
      .post('/tokens', { email: email, password: password })
      .then(response => {
        this.props.history.push('/') // Not working :(
      })
  }
}
```

When I inspect my app in the developer console I get a valid response, but I also get this: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'history' of undefined`.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a callback function:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import settings from '../settings'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

axios.defaults.baseURL = settings.hostname

export const login = ({ email, password }, callback) => {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios
      .post('/tokens', { email: email, password: password })
      .then(response => {
         //this.props.history.push('/') // Not working :(
         // do your stuff here ...
      })
      callback();
  }
}
```

and in your component:

```
this.props.login({email, password}, () => {
        this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access props via `this.props` in a React component defined with a function. Either define your component with a class, or add the "history" prop to the props parameter of your component function: `{email, password, history}`

Also, don't forget to link your component to the router, using withRouter and using the linked version in your code.
Usually we use something like

`export const Login = withRouter(LoginWithoutRouter)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking your time to help me fix this. Eventually I got really lazy and just wrote this:

`window.location.href = '/'`